# How to List Categories with Dropdown in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, drop-down-menu

I would like to add a dropdown menu to my Django project that lists all categories from the database. The challenge I'm facing is that while I can get the categories listed on a single page (category), I would like them to be accessible throughout the entire website.

views.py

```
 #dropdown list of categories
 class CategoryListView(View):
 template_name = 'media/categories_dropdown.html'  

 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'categories': categories})
```

urls.py

```
path('category/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-list'),
```

media/categories_dropdown.html

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <option value="{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where [inclusion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) tags are used, here is an example:

templates/dropdown.html:

```
<select name="categories">
    {% for category in categories %}
        <option value="{{category.slug}}">{{category.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

app_name/templatetags/dropdown.py:

```
from django import template
from app_name.models import Category

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("dropdown.html")
def category_dropdown():
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'categories': categories}
```

Then load the template tag in your main html like this:

```
{% load dropdown %}

{% category_dropdown %}
```